# How to make nameservers based on my domain name in Amazon EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, nameserver

I purchased Amazon EC2 instance and installed Ubuntu Server on it.

I have domain name example.com , the current nameserver of my domain is : ns1.hostcompany.com , ns2.hostcompany.com .

I want to point mydomain.com to the Instance and make nameservers like ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com. I have an Elastic IP associated with the instance.

Comment: To point your domain at the instance, create an A record pointing to your elastic IP address. For the name servers, firstly - some registrars require that name servers map to at least 2 different IP addresses - which is not possible with one instance. If that isn't an issue, then you will need to setup a DNS server (e.g. Bind - named; tinydns, etc). Unless you have a good reason for doing so, stick with your existing name servers - they are likely geographically distributed, will offer better performance, and don't need you to maintain them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://aws.amazon.com/route53/

I'd use route 53, cheap and easy to setup dns inside of amazon aws.

Answer (score 1):

First you need at least one DNS server, but preferably two that hold a copy of your domain.com zone. Then you need to call your registrar and do two things:

1) Make them authoritative for your zone

2) Register a glue record for the new servers

Answer (score 0):

You have to install bind or some other nameserver daemon and configure it to be your primary or secondary nameserver.

Then you have to ask your dns registrar to let you use your own server as a primary/secondary nameserver and to modify the registration database. Or you can do this yourself based on what interface your registrar provides to you.

But to maintain geographical redundancy of your name server you should use your registrars nameserver as primary/secondary or purchase another EC2 instance in another region.